# Nodejs callback value return

Tags: node.js, callback, es6-promise

I have calling a method to get datas and trying to return its datas however the get variable is coming as 'false'. Are there any way to return the datas from the get function?

```
    function GetDatas(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var get = Client.get(key, (err, result) => {
      if (err || !result) {
        return 'no data';
      }
      return result;
    });
    console.log(get);
    resolve(get);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Client.get` has a callback, you can not return data with the `return` call. Do it like this:

```
function GetDatas(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var get = function( callback ) {

        Client.get(key, function( err, result ) {
          if (err || !result) {
            callback( "No data" );

            return false;

          }

            callback( false, result );

        });

    };

    get(function( error, data ) {

        console.log(data);

        resolve( data );

    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that helped!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.

Comment: Why mix in the callback rather than just calling resolve in the the original function??

Comment: Because I tried to follow his original design. I dont see what changing the overall design does other than confuse him even more